# Error reading commands.properties, using local instead - Error Selenium Java

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

## **My dependecies**

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>`
```

## MY CODE MAIN

```
 WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--user-agent=MiUserAgentPersonalizado");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://www.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxx/HPSGDec10A");
```

......
**
In my window it works normally but when I deploy my java application to linux server with jboss
this error show me**

---

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector - Error reading commands.properties, using local instead

```
 WARN  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector - Exception reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE to get latest version of chromedriver (Connect to https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443 [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/64.233.186.128, chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/64.233.190.128, chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/142.250.0.128, chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/142.251.0.128, chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/172.217.192.128] failed: connect timed out)
```

**PLEASE, I want to know if I need a specific version of Chrome or what kind of configuration I need to do.**

Comment: looks like it's trying to download information about the latest chromedriver and that bit is failing.  "failed: connect timed out"  So it's using the local version of the driver.

Comment: @pcalkins ok, so  what kind of configuration I need to do.  a specific version? or another configuration

Comment: looks like it's trying to read a remote configuration file.   If you want to use the webdrivermanager, you need to fix the connection issue on that machine.  So go to the Linux server and try navigating to: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443  Maybe that'll tell you something about what's wrong there.  (note the ports used in the URLs in the exception... maybe some are being blocked?)

Comment: Yeah  @pcalkins , I just created a method to ping that uri, look at the image https://ibb.co/tPC0dZg, then this response in my postman on linux server https://ibb.co/hXgGrxC, but my windows https://ibb.co/jyWPx8c ,I assume it is the linux server firewall?